# Create an integer array downwards in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Is this a good way for create a downwards array from the range operator `..`?

```
@array = reverse 1..9;
for my $i (@array) {
    print $i." "
}

# Output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

The question comes from the fact that the more obvious @array = 9..1; doesn't work

Comment: I use Perl 5.26.1
No problem with the expression but I'm new to Perl (I come from Python) so, I want to figure out if doing this way is a good practice.

Comment: @GMB: From the [documentation for the range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) - "If the left value is greater than the right value then it returns the empty list."

Answer (score 3):

The main idea behind Perl is that [there's more than one way to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it). It's fundamentally different from Python in that regard.

Your code works, but it has a few flaws. If you're learning to code in Perl right now, pick these best practices up early.

- Always `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every program you write to help with debugging and catch errors early.
- Declare variables with `my` in the smallest scope possible. That creates a lexical variable that only exists within that scope.

Now for the multiple ways, all of the following produce the same result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = reverse 1..9;

foreach my $i ( @array1 ) {
  print "$i ";
}

# for and foreach can be used interchangeably 
for my $i (reverse 1..9) {
  print $i . ' ';
}

# post-fix for/foreach
print "$i " for @array1;

# join an array, eliminates trailing space
print join ' ', @array1;

# interpolate the array, automatically joins on $, variable, 
# which is a single space by default
print "@array1";
```

Comment: I see an empty array with the expression: 9..1
Could it be because of my Perl version 5.26.1?

Comment: @framontb you're right. On my 5.26.1 it doesn't work either. I didn't run my code before, just trusted the first comment on the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @simbabque: `9 .. 1` doesn't work. It's never worked. It's documented not to work :-)

Comment: @DaveCross I thought that too. Didn't look, trusted that other person. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Two shorter versions

```
for  (reverse 1..9) {print "$_ "}
```

or

```
print "$_ " for  (reverse 1..9)
```